# Refactor method into a generic method

Tags: vb.net, mvvm

I have this proper working method:

```
Public Shared Function Create(panelName As String, panelCaption As String) As ViewModelA
    Return ViewModelSource.Create(Function() New ViewModelA() With {
        .Name = panelName,
        .Caption = panelCaption
    })
End Function
```

which creates and returns an object of type *ViewModelA* with its properties *Name* and *Caption*.

(Note: *ViewModelSource.Create* is a method of a 3d party MVVM-Framework, that returns an instance of the given POCO class (here: *ViewModelA*)).

This method is needed by a couple of ViewModels and every ViewModel actually has its own method. This methods only differs in the type (*ViewModelA, ViewModelB, ViewModelC ...*).

What I want to achive is only one single generic method that returns an object of the type given as parameter - like the following fantasy code:

```
Public Shared Function Create(Of T)(panelName As String, panelCaption As String) As T
    Return ViewModelSource.Create(Function() New T With {
        .Name = panelName,
        .Caption = panelCaption
    })
End Function
```

and using the method like this:

```
Dim vmA As ViewModelA = Create(Of ViewModelA)("myName", "myCaption")
```

Comment: Why you need `Create` method? You know the type `ViewModelA` and required values - so you can use `new ViewModel A With {.Name = "name", .Caption = "caption"}`

Comment: It is a need of the MVVM Framework (DevExpress MVVM) to create the ViewModels with the ViewModelSource.Create method to take the advantages of this framework.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about an implementation of the [factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html).